# How ExtJS form panel bodyPadding do not padding form buttons

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am reading the extjs [offical tutorial](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/tutorials/login_app.html) to create a login form, so I create following login form window:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.login.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'login',

    requires: [
        'Ext.form.Panel',
        'Ext.form.field.Display',
        'Ext.form.field.Text'
    ],

    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Login Window',
    closable: false,
    autoShow: true,

    items: {
        xtype: 'form',
        reference: 'form',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'username',
            fieldLabel: 'Username',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'password',
            inputType: 'password',
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            hideEmptyLabel: false,
            value: 'Enter any non-blank password'
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Login',
            formBind: true,
            listeners: {
                click: 'onLoginClick'
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

here is the screenshot:

[image]

Please notice the "Login" button, it was wrapped by a gray background, but it was padding 10px white space with window.

How can `bodyPadding` do not padding the bottom button withou white space with the parent window? Just Like following picture:

[image]

I am using extjs6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `bodyPadding` from the window down to the form. The body doesn't include docked items.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jfa).